# write formula to predict nth term of sequence $1, 1\cdot3, 1\cdot3\cdot5, 1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot(2n-1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I write a formula for a sequence with the following behavior:

{$1, 1\cdot3, 1\cdot3\cdot5, 1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7, 1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9$}

1st term is $1$

2nd term is $1 \cdot 3 = 3$

3rd term is $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 15$

4th term is $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 105$

Please show steps on how to arrive at the answer:

Ted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic trick is to multiply and divide by the even terms:

$$
a_n=1\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-1)=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot \dots\cdot 2n}{2\cdot 4\cdot (2n)}
$$

The numerator is $(2n)!$. As for the denominator, we can factor each of the $n$ terms by $2$, so the denominator is $2^nn!$.

Finally, $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$

Comment: Your answer is off slightly, however the approach looks correct.

Comment: Looks right to me, @Patrick.

Comment: @Patrick: where is the problem? If you don't like dots, you can use $\prod$. Or check the formula by induction.

Comment: Oops, looked at it too quickly.  It's correct.

Comment: Would it work like this as well: (2n-1)!/(2^n(n-1)!) ?

Comment: What if I wanted only the even numbers 2, 2*4, 2*4*6, 2*4*6*8

Comment: @Ted: Why don't you try on your own? It is a good practice to check if you understood the method. Another formula for your product would be $\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}$ (can you see why the power of 2 is $n-1$?)

Comment: I did.. but I just don't know how to represent the product of the sequence at the bottom such that 1*3*(2n-1).

Comment: Don't you have the answer in this post?

Comment: Yea that's right, 2^n n! would be the answer, thanks Taladris

Answer (score 0):

We call it [Double Factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html), which can be expressed in terms of the gamma function by

$$\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\sqrt{\pi}.$$